# Problem with FallbackRoute in Servicestack

Tags: servicestack

I am using the Servicestack react template and I have noticed that in chrome I get errors in the console which indicate that the manifest.json is inaccessible.  After some poking around, I believe the issue is with the fallbackroute.

Initially the template contains the fallbackroute as follows:

```
[FallbackRoute("/{PathInfo*}", Matches="AcceptsHtml")]
```

Which makes sense since manifest.json is not html so I can see why I get a 403 error.

However, after changing the route to:

```
[FallbackRoute("/{PathInfo*}", Matches = @"PathInfo =~ \/(index\.html|manifest\.json|favicon\.ico)$")]
```

Which to my understanding should match index.html or manifest.json or favicon.ico, still does not work.  Index.html and favicon.ico work just fine, however I get a 'forbidden' error when requesting manifest.json which is strange because the file is in the same folder with the same permissions as the other 2 files.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any static files you want to allow need to be specified in [Config.AllowFileExtensions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/d371771d9b9b85442e29aa3e4468b49e15cc7618/src/ServiceStack/HostConfig.cs#L90), to allow access to `.json` static files, add the extension in your `HostConfig`, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    AllowFileExtensions = { "json" }
});
```

Comment: Do you think it would be helpful to have a small note somewhere in this section [http://docs.servicestack.net/routing#custom-rules] that says exactly what you said here (including the link)?  And no, I'm not being sarcastic (tone doesn't carry via text), I am aware that putting every possible detail all over the place in the docs can be overwhelming and NOT helpful.

Comment: @Bitfiddler it doesn't have anything to do with Routing, it's a security restriction to prevent unwanted leaking of static files. I'll look into adding a page/section on static file handling.